# Static When Recording From My Mixer

Tags: audio-recording, mixing, mixer

So i have a Behringer DJX900USB Mixer and im trying to record a mix
but i have this horrible static-y feedback kind of noise when i listen back too it 
ive tried turning the input level down (On both Audacity and Ableton) but still nothing.. im using a usb from the back of my mixer, could it be the wire? 
any help appreciated 
-Nath

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like your USB is bi-directional and you are possibly feeding the input straight back into the output again which is then being fed from your computer back into the mixer. Try de-activating usb input on the desk and only use the usb output.